# SKMapview is not active when selecting a row in UISearchDisplay results tableview

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, skmaps

I'm working in SKMaps. I'm searching for locations using UISearchDisplayController. When i select a location in ResultsTableView, the map shown correctly. But i could not drag the map. I set UserInteractionEnabled to true, but it's not working. Please give me suggestions.